# React Native: Cannot access location using geolocation API

Tags: react-native, geolocation

[image: Not actual screenshot of the code. But error is same]
Error: **Looks like the app doesn't have the permission to access location. Add the following line to your app's AndroidManifest.xml**

Even though I have added the permissions in manifest.xml and asking for runtime permissions I cannot access GPS.

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.location">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
.....
.....
```

complete code:

```jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View,
 PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  async requestLocationPermission() {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
          'title': 'Location Access Permission',
          'message': 'Expensify would like to use your location ' +
                     'so you we track you.'
        }
      )
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log("You can use the location")
      } else {
        console.log("Location permission denied")
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err)
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("compdidmount");
    this.requestLocationPermission();
//Crashes here on getCurrentPosition
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          (position) => {
            console.log(position.coords.latitude);
           },
           (error) => {
            console.log(error)
          },
          {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 10000}
        );
    }
      render() {
        return (
          <View style>
            <Text style>
              Tracking App
            </Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you await your `requestLocationPermission`-function before calling the `getCurrentPosition`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by **deleting and reinstalling** the application.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue with the `CameraRoll`. I fixed this asking for permission when the app starts. You should use this :

```
import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';

async function requestCameraPermission() {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      {
        'title': 'Location Permission',
        'message': 'Location Permission' +
                   'so you can use GPS location.'
      }
    )
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log("You can use GPS")
    } else {
      console.log("GPS location denied")
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err)
  }
}
```

Comment: Already added in code. Since, I'm testing it on Android 5.1. It doesn't asks for run-time permissions. I have not tested it on Android 6+ yet :/

Comment: Hey, @oma can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61361533/how-to-activate-gps-icon-in-react-native) question?